# Bootstrap tooltip and popover making double requests

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I'm having a problem with Bootstrap's popover where it will make 2 AJAX requests every time it processes "show".

With that in mind, I'm working on using AJAX to populate the popover and having 2 requests each time is not my idea of a good thing.

Does anybody have any ideas to knock this down to 1 request?
Here is the jsFiddle which shows the same issue with tooltip (which popover extends). http://jsfiddle.net/Handyman/NBkKE/1/

Html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12" id="content">
        <div class="span6">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">item1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">item2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">item3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">item4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
var $counter = 0;
$('#content').tooltip({
html: true,
trigger: 'hover',
placement: 'bottom',
container: '#container',
title: function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {
            item1data: 'some data for item 1',
            item2data: 'some data for item 2'
        },
        success: function($response)
        {
            console.log($response);
        }
    });

    return 'testing' + ($counter++);
}
});
```

Comment: The tooltip library internally checks if there's content, then it show's the content. Both calls (`hasContent` and `setContent`) make a call to your `getTitle` method. If you set a breakpoint and examine the call stack you'll see what I'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/ccamarat/tz4qQ/ 
Using Ajax to populate a tooltip seems a little heavy to begin with; you might consider populating it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I was using title for both title and content.
Popover has a separate method for content.

So once I started using them correctly, I now only have 1 request made to the server.

New JS:

```
var $counter = 0;
$('#content').popover({
html: true,
trigger: 'hover',
placement: 'bottom',
container: '#container',
title: function()
{
    return $(this).text();
},
content: function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {
            item1data: 'some data for item 1',
            item2data: 'some data for item 2'
        },
        success: function($response)
        {
            console.log($response);
        }
    });

    return 'testing' + ($counter++);
}
});
```